# EditText does not show current input (Android 4)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My Android application contains an [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) view where you can type some short messages (single line). Pressing the keyboard's *DONE* key will append the message to a log view above ([TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)) and clear the input view.

Here's a snippet from my view xml:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To handle the input and reset the view, I use the [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html).

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    ...
    String input = mInputView.getText().toString();
    mInputView.setText(""); // clear the input view
    ...
}
```

#### The problem

I did not experience any problems on Android 1.6 - 3. But starting with IceCreamSandwich (>= Android 4) there's a weird bug which occurs intermittently (in most cases after ~10-30 inputs).

When you type some text, the input view remains blank. The cursor still blinks on position 0, no text is shown. Though a click on *DONE* adds the (invisible) text to the log view above and the text can be read. Also hiding the keyboard makes the text in the EditText view visible.

#### Solution

As stated in the accepted answer this is a (not so much) known bug of the Android OS. The simple solution is to clear the EditText view in a different way:

```
TextKeyListener.clear(mInputView.getText());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue, even on lower API levels. There's a bug when using:

```
editText.setText("");
```

many times to empty an EditText. Here's a workaround that helped:

```
TextKeyListener.clear(editText.getText());
```

You can read about this bug on the Google Code site: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17508

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

try setting an `OnClickListener` on your done button.  Have the `onClick(View v)`  look like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    kontextTV1.setText(editText1.getText.toString());
}
```

If you pull the text when the user hits the done button, you won't have to use a watcher class.  This should also work on all versions of android.  (Get/Set on edittext and textview aren't likely to change).  That will handle a

If you want to handle the 'done' button on they keyboard, try:

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(final View v, final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I add an OnClickListener on the DONE button of the virtual keyboard? I don't think that this is possible. If, though, does it also work on hardware keyboards and third-party virtual keyboard, e.g. HTC Sense?

Comment: I must have misread your question, edited response to show how to do this.

Comment: Your solution works, but it does not fix the bug I've got using an OnEditorActionListener. After a series of inputs, the EditText does not show the input :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not use afterTextChanged instead of editorActionListener?

Comment: The user submits his input with the DONE key, this is very important! Also an empty input has to be submittable. So I can't use a TextChangedListener, right?